# WebBrowser object replacement

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm now searching for an object to use in my C# winform project instead of the regular Webbrowser object that comes with VS 2010.
Does someone knows of a good other option?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there are many alternatives, in the end the WebBrowser control is just the IE installed on your computer. What is the reason this control doesn't match with your requirements?

Comment: It's not reliable. It's working fine on one page one day and the next day it can't find objects on the same exact page. Also the document completed event sometimes won't fire. I tried dealing with it, but no success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) or [Gecko](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/)